# Draw NSString right justified with NSString.draw(in rect: withAttributes: ) in MacOS?

Tags: macos, nsstring, draw

Cannot draw a String right justified in NSView ( MacOs )
Here is my code, which crashes with :

-[__SwiftValue lineBreakMode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600003408750

```
let attrs = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:NSColor.white,
                     NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle:NSTextAlignment.right
                    ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]

            let absolutPoint = NSPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
            var convertedPt  = convertPoint(dataPoint:se,scaleX:scaleX,scaleY:scaleY)
            convertedPt.x    = absolutPoint.x
            
            let scalaLabel = NSString(format:"%3.0f",se.y)

            let place = NSMakeRect(convertedPt.x, convertedPt.y, 80.0, 12.0)
            scalaLabel.draw(in:place ,withAttributes:attrs )
```

If I do not set **paragraphStyle** in **attrs**, text is drawn correctly. But not right-justified.
Any idea what´s wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 5):

```
NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle:NSTextAlignment.right
```

That's not valid, that's why it's crashing. 
The value should be a `NSParagraphStyle`, not a `NSTextAlignment` as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key/1527910-paragraphstyle):

> The value of this attribute is an `NSParagraphStyle` object. Use this
> attribute to apply multiple attributes to a range of text. If you do
> not specify this attribute, the string uses the default paragraph
> attributes, as returned by the `default` method of `NSParagraphStyle`.

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = .right

let attrs = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:NSColor.white,
             NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
            ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
```

Side note, if you state the type before, it might be shorten:

```
let attrs: NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [foregroundColor: NSColor.white,
                                           paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]
```